# Stop a scrollfollow div on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar which are scrollfollow, that means it works as it is set to position:fixed. However, the sidebar continue scrolling till the user stop. This results in the elements on the bottom of the site doesn't reach the sight of the user, because the sidebar push elements down.

I have created a fiddle to illustrate the exact problem: `jsd` https://jsfiddle.net/Lv4humd6/2/

The javascript that makes the div scrollfollow:

```
$(function() {

var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar-right"), 
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 15;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});  
});
```

What I want is the sidebar to stop scrolling, when it reach the div **break** as you see in the jsfiddle. I have searched and tried everything, but I can't find any solution for it.